# Merging Cluster Lists from Multiple Algorithms: Identifying Methods and SQL Implementation

Tags: python, sql, algorithm, pyspark, cluster-analysis

I'm facing a challenge in merging lists of clusters generated by different algorithms using the same set of data items, identifiable by their IDs. Each algorithm clusters these IDs based on varying attributes (which I'll omit for irrelevance here), with the largest ID in each cluster being the cluster key (using max is a decion made to have a deterministic key selection, it is not a requirement).

Consider the following example with items represented by their IDs ranging from 1 to 8:

Example items

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| ... |
| 8 |

*Clustering results from two different algorithms:*

**Clustering 1**

| cluster_key | id |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 |

**Clustering 2**

| cluster_key | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 |

**Expected Output**

| cluster_key | id |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 8 | 8 |

The Logic Behind the Expected Output:

Clusters from both lists that share even one ID should be merged. For instance, clusters 3 and 6 from the first list overlap with clusters 1, 2, 3, 5, and 6 from the second list. Therefore, they are merged into a single cluster with a key of 6. Similarly, cluster 8 is identical in both lists.

**My Questions:**
Is there a recognized name for this kind of problem in data clustering or algorithms, and are there any existing literature or studies on it?
Are there known SQL implementations or approaches for solving this? Any pyspark or even python implementations are welcome as well.

My thoughts so far

1. We can consider each "table" or "cluster list" as correct, and if we can prove that we can merge two correct lists into a correct list, then it's solved
2. The merging of two cluster lists is reminicent of the Union Find data structure, where we'd have to call on `Find(n)` for each `n` in the set of IDs.

My attepmpt at robust definitions:

1. A cluster list is correct when

   - every ID has exactly one cluster ID
   - every cluster has at least one ID
   - every cluster's ID can be deterministically derived given all the IDs in the cluster (this is why we use max)
2. When merging two cluster lists

   - initially, both lists `left` and `right` are correct
   - for any two clusters `A` (from left) and `B` (from right) where A and B shared at least one id, then all the IDs in both clusters must be in the same cluster
   - the former is transitive, for example, if clusters `A`, `B`, and `C` on the left and clusters `Y`, and `Z` on the right are formed in such a way that `A` and `B` both share items with `Y`, and `B` and `C` both share items with `Z`, then the outcome would be a single unified cluster (I'm cognizant that this is condensed information, but I wanted to avoid a larger data-driven example).
3. I feel like there are other situations or conditions to consider when merging these cluster lists, but my intelligence seems to be more limited than my intuition in this case.

I'm looking for guidance or suggestions on how to approach this problem, especially if there are SQL-based solutions or similar algorithmic strategies.

Thank you for your help!

**Approaches that didn't work**

1. Union all and self-join

- we attempted a self-join of the union of the two cluster lists, but that failed at the transitive join requirement

1. matrix approach with row max

- fails at considering the multiple items in each cluster (see IDs 1 and 2)

| id | cluster_key1 | cluster_key_2 | row_max | correct_outcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | 3 | 6 |
| 3 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 6 |
| 4 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 6 |
| 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |
| 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 | 8 |

Comment: Update: learned that the problem is generally referred to as cluster ensemble

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe this problem it sounds as if you want the connected components of the network where the nodes are all the different clusters of all the different clusterings and there is an edge between two nodes if they share at least one element. I have some knowledge of SQL (not extensive) and as far as I know this cannot be expressed in SQL. Note that a connected component can have a large diameter, that is, many hops (steps along edges) are needed to visit it entirely. An example of this would be if there were clusters (a,b) (b,c) (c,d) (d,e) (e,f) - you'd need all of these nodes in a single cluster and it takes four steps to get from (a,b) to (e,f). It is a relatively simple problem, you need the transitive closure of the relationship "two clusters share at least one element"; there are many software packages that can compute connected components. You would need to

- label each cluster, keep track of which elements they have
- compute which clusters are connected (by sharing elements)
- output `<L1>` `<L2>` labels when two clusters are connected
- use this format to compute connected components using a package (or a custom script, it is not a complicated problem)
- the output is a list of sets of labels
- for each set of labels, merge all the elements of the corresponding clusters

This (transitive closure approach) could lead to very few clusters due to the effect of chaining. It is a slightly unusual thing to do; where you mention *cluster ensemble*, I think that it is usually used in the context of *consensus clustering*, where the goal is to find some kind of intermediate/compromise or "wisdom of the crowd" improved clustering. As an aside, the above approach (and how you formulate the problem) can be described as *single link clustering of all clusters in the ensemble based on non-empty overlap*.